# Eloquent migration not working

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code

```
Scheme::create(function(Blueprint table) {
    $table->increments("id");
}
```

can anyone tell me why this isn't working? I don't know why..

Comment: Because argument should be `$table` and not `table`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you didn't name your database, and it's `Schema`

```
Schema::create('assignments', function(Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
 });
```

Hope this helps.

---